# Android Google Map Location Updates NOT WORKING

Tags: android, google-maps

My last known location is not updating but with the `googlemap.setMyLocationEnable(true)` my location is updating. Can anyone help? Here is my code:

```
private void setUpMap() {

    if(googlemap == null) {

        googlemap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        if(googlemap != null) {         
            googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            String provider = lm.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);

            if (provider == null){
                onProviderDisabled(provider);
            }

            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
            Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if (loc != null) {
                onLocationChanged(loc);
            }

            googlemap.setOnMapLongClickListener(onLongClickMapSettings());
        }
    }
}

private OnMapLongClickListener onLongClickMapSettings() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new OnMapLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i(arg0.toString(), "User long clicked");
        }
    };
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    googlemap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
    googlemap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

    Marker ME = googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(latlng)
    .title("Current Location(You)")
    .snippet("Current")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.user_marker)));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing the old and new way of using Google Maps on Android.

If you use the new way (v2, recommended), you don't have to instantiate a LocationManager and then request for location updates with that.

Please check here, on the official documentation, how to do things in the proper way: https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

You simply have to implement `LocationListener` and, of course, when you create your `LocationRequest` object set the correct parameters based on your needs.

If you're not using the v2 version of the API for Android, I kindly suggest you to do so starting from https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html.